# getting xhttp.status = 0 for posting data in my google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script, xmlhttprequest

I'm New to chrome extensions.

I'm Creating a chrome extension in which i need to store an array containing the user id's as a column in my google spreadsheet.

below is the code for sending data to the spreadsheet.

```
var setStatus = 'inserting';
function createXHR() {  
    try {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
}
$.each(caseIds, function(index, caseId){
    caseId = JSON.stringify(caseId);
    var postData = createXHR();
    postData.open('GET', trixUrl, true);
    postData.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    postData.onreadystatechange = function() {
        alert("The Readystate is :" +
          postData.readyState +
          " and the status is :"+postData.status
        );
    };
    postData.send("&CaseID="+caseId+"&flag="+setStatus);
});
```

Below is the trixUrl path

```
var trixUrl  = "https://script.google.com/a/macros/google.com/s/AKfycbw8pjHJau91KdlqMjQr9XEEoI_ZET2J3xXkL7e-fH-7/dev"
```

AppScript Code:

```
function doGet(e) 
{
Logger.log(e);
var method, newvar, sheetObject, sheetOne;
var newvar = e.parameter.CaseID;
Logger.log(newvar);
var method= e.parameter.flag;
Logger.log(method);
}
```

And I'm getting bellow error in the AppScript log

```
[16-05-27 04:03:37:622 PDT]{parameter{},contextPath=,contentLength=-1,queryString=null, parameters={}}
[16-05-27 04:03:37:623 PDT] undefined
[16-05-27 04:03:37:623 PDT] undefined
```

Could any one please help me with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974442/empty-response-from-push-notification), the post body is retrieved in the `postData object`.

```
function doPost(e) {
Logger.log(e.postData.getDataAsString());
}
```

You can used the following code to get the content.

```
function doPost(request)
{      
  //Logger.log(request.getContentText("UTF-8"));

  // do something with the contents ...
  /*for (p in request.parameters)
  {

    Logger.log (p.toString());
  }*/

  var xmlDoc = Xml.parse(request.postData.contents );
}
```

Check this related [forum](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2158).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs abielita. But the request from the backrdound.js is itself not coming to the appscrips.